# Paypal Restful API availability Australia

Tags: api, rest, paypal, restful-architecture

We have worked with a developer to build a new website in Australia using the Paypal Restful API - all worked well during development using the sandbox.  When we attempted to enable live payments we received the following message;

**Note: Direct credit card processing is not available for you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are inoperable for direct credit card processing for your country but your test credentials are enabled for sandbox testing.**

Further investigation seems to indicate the Restful API is available in Australian dollars but not in Australia.

Can someone confirm this is correct?. Any ideas why Restful API is not available in Australia?  (I'm guessing maybe because PayPal purchased Braintree in Australia and they are pushing this solution here).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In REST API, direct credit card payment is only available for US and UK merchants. If you integrate PayPal by REST API , buyer need to pay with PayPal account.

Comment: Thanks Zhao.  What are our options for accepting credit card payments on our own site?  Can we use Braintree v.zero or should we use PayPal Payments Pro?

Comment: You are welcome ! yes,please try to use Payments Pro or Braintree.